# Hold phrasal verb for “waiting until something happens”

Tags: phrasal-verbs

I'm looking for the "hold" phrasal verb that means that I will stop doing something until something else is ready.

> John's report is input to my task so I will wait for that

Would that be:

> John's report is input to my task so I will **hold off/on/back** for that

?

Comment: You'll **hold off** until that. ('Hold on' also works.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confusingly, both "off" and "on" are often a part of this idiomatic construction: "John is still working on his report, so I will **hold off on** my task." "Hold on!" by itself means "Wait!" It doesn't have to have an object. You could yell "Hold on!" as somebody went out a door to have them stop and wait. "Hold off" specifically is about waiting *to do* something. So you could also say "John's report isn't ready, so I'll *hold on* until it is."